# Is the attribute selector syntax for class names necessary in HTML emails in 2022?

Tags: css, html-email

I have an old email template contributed to by several people and it uses an attibute selector to select the class attribute value in addition to the normal class selector.

```
*[class=hide], .hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Every media query selector in the email is set up this way using square brackets in the first selector.

I'm trying to figure out if this usage can be removed in favor of only the regular dot syntax `.className` selectors.

Searching around, I can see that at least at some point, Yahoo Mail [required this syntax within media queries](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/262-classname-vs-img-class-classname-vs-img-class-classname).

Where is the attribute selector syntax for class names necessary in HTML emails in 2022?

Comment: I'm guessing because desktop Office Outlook (probably) doesn't support it (seeming as Outlook's HTML email rendering capabilities are permanently stuck in 2007), so they're using this as a crude technique to hide style rules from Outlook - if that's the case then they should be using `[if mso]` conditional-comments instead: https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/

Comment: But then why would it be in combination with the normal selector?

Comment: Because CSS requires UAs to reject a rule in its entirety if they're unable to confidently parse _all_ of a rule's comma-separated selectors, but yes, I do agree that it seems redundant. Can't you track down the person that made the change and ask them directly? (`git blame`, etc)? Otherwise, you might want to consider just removing any suspect CSS rules if you think they might be examples of cargo-cult-programming.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But is it still necessary to use attribute selectors for Yahoo Mail?

Comment: People still use Yahoo mail?

Comment: Lol, it's in our list of supported email clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required. In fact, if you do it, there are risks depending on what is written that Gmail apps will delete your entire `<style>` block. You are right that it was an old Yahoo requirement (and that requirement has passed).

So definitely use normal classes, if you need embedded styles at all (you should rarely need them, since most of the styles need to be inline as many email environments don't support embedded styles - see https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-style/).

You might also like to lookup what other selectors are currently supported here: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=selector

Generally, we only need to use embedded styles for progressive enhancement.

Comment: Haven't we answered that? Yahoo. The link for further detail is in the question.